# Read from stdin or multiple file arguments

Tags: c, linux

What my main is supposed to do is either read from stdin using system calls. Or if file arguments are given open the file arguments. I had already coded this to read from one file argument.  But now I need it to open from multiple file arguments and I am short on the logic as to how to do this. How would I get my code to be able to open multiple file arguments?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *file_pathname = NULL;
    int fd;
    char file_buffer[540];

    //Check for proper number of arguments:
    if(argc < 2) {
        exit(2);
    }

    if(argc < 3) {
        file_pathname = "stdin";
    }

    file_pathname = argv[2];   

    if(argc < 3) {
        ((fd = read(STDIN_FILENO,file_buffer, FILE_BUFFER_SIZE)));
    }
    // FILE argument given, so try to open it:
    if (argc == 3) {
        if ((fd = open(file_pathname,O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR OPENING FILE");
            return 2;
        }
```

Comment: `for(int i=2; i<argc; i++) { fname = argv[i]; ... }`

Comment: I need to just be able to open multiple file arguments. So every file argument at argv2 argv3 argv4........  Open each of those files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your program run only on linux (POSIX Compatible) system you can be interested in

```
man 3 getopt
```

This is function that can help you to parse command line arguments in short unix style, for example:

```
myprog -a 5654 -f -n ~/Test/input.txt
```

There are also getopt_long() and getopt_long_only() if you want to parse long options.

If you want some specific argument parser(which i do NOT recommend), you can implement it as library.

There are glib parser if you are using glib or gtk. Or a parser in qxt (an extension Qt library) if you have a qt project. Or you can just google for more lightweight cross-platform argument parsers if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a function that gets a file descritor and does what you want:

```
void do_stuff(int fd);
```

Add another one, which does the same with a file name:

```
void do_stuff_fname(const char *fname);  /* Open fname and call do_stuff */
```

Now, your `main` should call either:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    do_stuff(STDIN_FILENO);
} else {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) do_stuff_fname(argv[i]);
}
```

You can improve this by using `getopt`, as [JustAnotherCurious suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514609/1111371)